# How to resolve Quadratic Equation via a function method java?

Tags: java, function

Please help me to resolve Quadratic Equation with a function method.

I have 2 classes:

The `void` class and the `function` class.

I want to call the `function` class to resolve a Quadratic Equation. How do I call the `function` class?
`void` class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class task53 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
    double a, b,c;
    System.out.println("please input int for  Quadratic equation");

    System.out.println( " a -int input  ");
    a= sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println( " b -int input ");
    b= sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println( " c -int input ");
    c= sc.nextInt();

   System.out.println(Function.tenlikkok(a, b));

  }
}
```

`function` class:

```
public class Function {
  public static double  D(double a, double b, double c, double resultD) {

    resultD = Math.pow(b,2) - 4*a*c;
    return   resultD();

  }

  public static double   root (double a, double b) {

    double D =Function.tenlikD(a, b, c, resultD);


    if (D > 0){
        double x1,x2;
        x1 = (-b - Math.sqrt(D))/(2*a);
        x2 = (-b + Math.sqrt(D))/(2*a);
        System.out.println(" x1 = " +x1 + " x2 = "  +x2 );
    }
    else if (D==0){
        double x;
        x = -b/(2 * a);
        System.out.println(" x1 = x2 = " + x);
        } else  {
      System.out.println("no root");
    }

    return D;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you're defining your `tenlikkok` or `tenlikD` methods.

Comment: Similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813045/solving-quadratic-equation-using-methods-java?rq=1

Comment: You seem to be having a few problems in your code. I believe the answer to your question is `System.out.println(Function.root(a, b));`. However, `root()` returns the discriminant, so this is what it will print, in addition to what `root()` prints itself.

Answer (score 0):

Although code is quite unclear, as is your question, I believe you are trying to implement methods from the class `Function` in class `task53`, maybe? To do that, you could write this line under `public class task53{`

`Function func = new Function();`

and implement a method from `Function` by doing `func.method()`.

Comment: Since `Function` contains only static methods, as it stands there is no point in instantiating it (no point in `new Function()`). It’s considered better style just to do `Function.staticMethod()` (or make the methods non-static).